# How do I increase a variable incrementally while a button is held in jquery?

Tags: jquery, button, click

I'm trying to set up a simple program in which a variable increases steadily while a button is being held, and stops when the button is inactive. I've fiddled around with .mousedown but I can't seem to figure it out. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mousedown` event fires when you click the mouse button and the `mouseup` event fires when you release the button. You can utilize these in combination to detect when someone has clicked for a long time by setting an interval in the `mousedown` event handler and clearing that interval in the `mouseup` event handler. Thereby running code every X ms when the mouse is depressed and then stopping when the mouse is released.

You may also want to consider using the `mouseout` or jQuery-specific `mouseleave` event to stop the interval if the user makes the pointer leave the designated "click" area.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm really new to this stuff. What might that block of code look like if the variable being incremented is "mouseHeld"?